# Where can I change this value?

Tags: views, database

I'm trying to change the phone number displayed in sidebar window with the chinese lady in it. However I'm trying to find out where it's content is coming from.

[image]

This is how the HTML looks

```
<div class="headsetButton">
    <a href="#" class="clickSpan yyModChatLink"><?php print variable_get('yingyang_online_title1');?></a>
    <a href="#" class="youhuiSpan yyModChatLink"><?php print variable_get('yingyang_online_title2');?></a>
    <span class="numSpan"><?php print variable_get('yingyang_online_phone');?></span>
    <span class="hr"></span>
    <a class="onlineConsultation yyModChatLink" href="<?php print url('customer-contact-request') . '?width=790' ?>"></a>

    <div class="headsetHide"></div>
</div>
```

and the thing I need to change in particular is `<?php print variable_get('yingyang_online_phone');?>` but I can't find where *yingtang_online_phone* is set.

do you guys have any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) is used to store and retrieve systemic variables , you can found them in `system` table in DB, or you can change them using [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)

Comment: hmm, I don't have the 'system' table in my DB

Comment: The proper table is "variable"

Answer (score 0):

You should find form element 'yingtang_online_phone' in code of your site.

```
$form['yingtang_online_phone'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  ...
);
```